# Unable to activate rspec-2.12.0, because rspec-core-2.13.1 conflicts with rspec-core (~> 2.12.0)

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

When I try to do `rspec rspec_001.rb` I get the above error

How can I get around the error and run tests?

contents of `rspec_001.rb`:

```
require 'rspec'

class Dummy < Object
end

describe "a test" do
end
```

I can't seem to use `bundle exec rspec rspec_001.rb`   as this is not a Rails project with a Gemfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gem update rspec` fixed this and now the spec runs ("No examples found." is ok, there aren't any) -

```
rspec rspec_001.rb
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00011 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
```